# Using cURL command-line tool on Mac, how does one fetch stock data which comes back *without* commas?

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line, curl

The below script is not working.

```sh
cd desktop/quoteUpdate
while true
do
 curl-o quotes.txt -s "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=goog,aapl&f=sl1"
 sed -i '.bak' 's/,/ /g' quotes.txt
echo UPDATED:
date
sleep 10
done
```

When I try and run the executable I get this error and no txt file is created in my desktop folder.

```
UPDATED:
Wed 14 Jan 2015 15:33:30 GMT

    /Users/chrisdorman/Desktop/quoteUpdate/runNow: line 4: curl-o: command not found
    sed: quotes.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You need space after `curl` command. Try `curl -o`.

Comment: Ramesh what could I do to that script to fetch the stock data WITHOUT commas but with NO SPACES. ie 1,000,000 would be 1000000 then a space for delimiting

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you meant in your above comment. Please update your question with a sample input and the output that you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have spaces in the `curl` command. You should have `curl -o` instead of `curl-o`. If I include the spaces and run the command, I get the `quotes.txt` file as expected.

Comment: Ramesh this worked perfect. Thank you very much for helping. best regards

Comment: Thank you. Ramesh what could I do to this script if I wanted to take this one stage further and fetch the stock data WITHOUT commas as you showed me BUT with NO SPACES in the numerical data. ie 1,000,000 would be fetched as 1000000 followed by a space for the Excel delimiting.  The txt file is then taken over to Excel and I need to delimit it properly by having an adequate amount of space between each value fetched. ie 2000000 SPACE 4500000 SPACE 780000

Comment: @ChrisDormani, could you please add an example to your question with sample input and output that you are expecting?

Comment: The script changes you mentioned deliver the numerical data back to me without the commas which is perfect. What could I do to the script to bring the numerical data back not only without the comma but with NO spaces. right now it fetches 1 000 000 How could I script this to deliver such as 1000000.